# express.js next middleware tier being called when explicitly ending the response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I came across the following behaviour:

When I have multiple express middleware mounted, the request continues to cascade down to the next middleware, even though I explicitly end the request by using `res.json()` in the previous middleware. Also note that I'm NOT calling `next()` anywhere in said middleware.

```
app.use('/v1/status', function (req, res, next) {
    res.json({ status: 'ok' });
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('I always get called');
});
```

Is this 'new' behaviour? Because to my understanding (and the 4x docs) this should't happen.

Any help would be much appreciated.

express v4.13.0 on Mac OSX

Comment: res.json will not end the flow. you should  use return to end the flow

Comment: @Akshat - return wont work. From what i understand, `app.use` statements continue to be executed even after sending `res.json`. It's weird though. Same thing happens even if you use `res.end()` after sending the response.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work unfortunately. But that shouldn't even be necessary because `res.json()` is identical to `res.send()`, which in turn is identical to `res.end()`.

Comment: @danillouz - Try using `require('express').Router()` instead of `app`.

Comment: @danillouz, I think, you'll have to remove the function if you dont want that function to be called everyting. Define two different functions in middleware 
which are called depending error/ success condition

Comment: @danillouz - which one gets called first? (add a `console.log` in the "v1" handler)

Comment: @SwarajGiri I also tried it with `express.Router()`, same problem

Comment: @danillouz - If you put anything inside `app.use` it gets executed for every request. But, if you have a route middleware, `router.verb` not calling `next` pauses execution.

Comment: @Amit The middlewares get called in correct order when adding [console.logs](https://gist.github.com/danillouz/ac7e655b86831155d606)

Comment: @SwarajGiri - suppose your claim is correct. What is `next` used for then? why is it even there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the problem with the help of the amazing @dougwilson. He advised me to print the url that was being requested and there I saw `/favicon.ico` being printed.

Upon closer inspection I saw that the first middleware actually completed the request, but that the favicon request was still pending. Thats why the second middleware was being called. It had nothing to do with `res.json()` not working properly.

Never ran into this problem before and it was driving me crazy! Thanks for your help everyone!